# ¿Qué forma verbal es la correcta: habrá payasos o habrán payasos?

Tags: haber

Cuando se usa **haber** como verbo principal, ¿necesitamos concordar en número con el sustantivo?

Por ejemplo:

> **Hubo** muchos rumores 
> **Hubieron** muchos rumores

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, *haber* con el significado de existir en un lugar o tiempo es impersonal. En esa oración, *muchos rumores* no es el sujeto, sino el complemento directo. Si fuera el sujeto, no podríamos sustituirlo por *los*:

> **Los** hubo.

La concordancia es entre el núcleo del predicado y el sujeto, nunca con el complemento directo.

Answer (score 4):

A pesar de que es un error muy difundido utilizarlo en plural, "haber" como verbo principal siempre es impersonal y se conjuga en singular. El sustantivo o frase nominal que sigue al verbo es complemento directo, no sujeto:

- **Habrá** payasos - **Los** habrá.
- **Hubo** muchos errores - **Los** hubo.